# Make [keyframe] synonym of [css-animations] (or merge it with [css-keyframes])

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyframe) has 609 questions and all<sup>1</sup> are related to [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations)

The info show this:

> The @keyframes rule is used to create CSS animations.

Basically *keyframes* is a keyword used to create CSS animations so there is no need to have it as a separate tag. If you are facing issue with *keyframes* then you are for sure facing issue with CSS animations.

There is also the [css-keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-keyframes) that is already a synonym of [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations) making [keyframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyframe) redundant.

---

<sup>1</sup> If we consider the questions taggued with [*keyframe* that aren't taggued with *css* and *css-animation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyframe+-css+-css-animations) we have 125 questions and most of them are also related to CSS animations and the use of the CSS *@keyframes* rule.

Comment: As a [tag:css] Gold badger, I support synonymizing this (and have already voted as such on the tag wiki); it's a no-brainer.

Comment: What about the 149 questions matching [`[keyframe] -[css]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyframe+-css)?

Comment: [keyframe] is a more general term

Comment: @SamB i'd do `[keyframe] -[css*]`

Comment: @SamB most of the `[keyframe] -[css]` are related to CSS animation as you can see. So there is probably few that aren't related to CSS animation. In all the cases, we should either change the description of the tag to make it different or make it a synonym

Comment: I've added a new tag to reflect info from Daniel A White

Answer (score 10):

I object. Keyframes is a general term used in video production and Flash. [There are Maya and h264 questions in this query.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyframe+-css*)

Comment: Then the tag description should be changed. Actually most of the question use it for CSS animation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif agree.

Comment: or we consider [tag:keyframes] as the general one and we get rid of [tag:keyframe]

Comment: @TemaniAfif i'm fine with that too

Comment: Whichever retagging/synonymizing avenue requires less work should probably be pursued.

Comment: Or just retag the flash questions with [flash-keyframes], and merge the CSS ones to [css-animations].

Comment: @BhargavRao: It's hardly just flash; there are also questions about Blender, [`three.js`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Animation-system), and just general questions about the concept -- and that's only for the kind used in animation. Then there are still the questions involving keyframes in video streams, relating to ffmpeg, .NET, DirectShow, Android MediaCodec.  And I do see a *few* CSS questions left in this query, but nothing like "most".

Comment: Cool, if that's the case then let's just update the wiki. That should fix the issue with the tag.

Comment: @SamB questions about blender are off-topic unless related to python. Else there's another StackExchange for blender

Comment: @weegee: Well, I don't remember seeing any blender questions that didn't seem to be about programming it to do things, *probably* using python.  (I suspect anything more exotic would get <= 0 answers here.)

Comment: I rewrote the wiki to mention the general usage. Let me know if you want to rename the tag into [keyframes] instead of [keyframe]. Thanks (cc @TemaniAfif)